# Linux Server Socket to Windows Client Socket

Tags: c#, linux, windows, sockets

Hi im writing a code that will connect a windows client to a linux server socket. 
I can already established a connection but it seems like the linux server are always cutting my connection after a few seconds without sending me back the response i needed.
Also i already tried using telnet but again after a few seconds the linux server cut my connection.

Is there a problem connecting to a linux server socket using windows socket?

```
            IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("IPADDRESS"), 6004);
            // Create a TCP/IP  socket.
            Socket sender = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Connect the socket to the remote endpoint. Catch any errors.
            try
            {
                if (!sender.Connected)
                    sender.Connect(remoteEP);

                string data = new Client().Test();

                DE_ISO8583 de = new ISO8583().Parse(data);

                data = data.Length.ToString().PadLeft(4, '0') + data;
                byte[] msg = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                int bytesSent = sender.Send(msg);

                //// Receive the response from the remote device.
                int bytesRec = sender.Receive(bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Received = {0}",
                    Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec));

                //sender.Disconnect(true);

                //sender.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
                //sender.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ane)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException : {0}", ane.ToString());
            }
            catch (SocketException se)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException : {0}", se.ToString());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Unexpected exception : {0}", e.ToString());
            }
```

Comment: This is something that probably happens millions upon millions of times a day on systems worldwide, so I doubt there is any problem with the underlying infrastructure. Maybe if you gave more information about your code and what you are doing on the server we can help more.

Comment: Hi @RonBeyer , Im passing a ISO8583 message which is in bytes using sockets in windows c#. connecting and sending the data is ok, i got no errors from that but when i try to receive the response an error occured saying that the connection was forcibly close. i dont know what is happening behind that

Comment: Description helps but what you are using as code would go farther. Try creating the smallest section of code that recreates the problem and edit your post with the code.

Answer (score 0):

The server may be closing the connection due to no activity.  Enabling the keepalive option will send an empty datagram to the server periodically to keep the connection alive.  See code below

```css
            TcpClient client = new TcpClient();
            client.Client.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Tcp, SocketOptionName.KeepAlive, true);​
```

Comment: im using Socket not tcpclient :) sorry